# Cloud Station Backup creating lots of temp files

Tags: synchronization, synology, nas

my synology drive client version is 3.2.1-13272 . the synology drive client is creating many files in my nas server. it creates many temp files in my /home/drive/backup/myPC... .

and have temp files are located in my pc . that file in sync disk（ D:\clouddata\syndirectory）

Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Thanx a lot